# Correct phrasing of a classic math problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My dad told me he once had to solve a problem (enigma?) that runs along the lines of this phrasing:

> "a spy only successfully report that he saw the enemies planes in
>   fight formation. There were many of them First the planes formed a
>   triangle, then split into 2 triangles.  Can you deduce the number of
>   enemy planes ? "

Does it ring a bell for you ? Do you know the correct question ? I would love to solve it and share it with him.

Edit : I got the same results as @mvw and they are disappointing (many answers).  I think I do have an incorrect phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

That could be the correct formulation. The problem is about which (whole) numbers can be represented as triangles. This image shows that 1, 3, 6, 10 and 15 are all such numbers:

[image]

Not every number can be, however (the numbers 3 or 4, for instance). You can look up "triangular number" if this isn't clear.

Thus you know that the total number of planes is a triangular number, and they then split into two groups, each of which contained a (smaller) triangular number of planes. In order to be able to claim you've solved the problem, you'd need to show that there's only one possible number of total planes that would work. There's definitely at least one number that would work, but it's quite a small number, so perhaps the reason the question mentions that there were "many" planes is to rule out that answer.

Comment: But you made a strong assumption on the triangles topology.  How do you know this is the way the planes are ordered : +1 at each rows and not +2. Do you know the problem or a variant?

Comment: @Poutrathor If we make no assumptions about the triangles, the problem is clearly unsolvable because any number of planes could be arranged into *some* formation that looks acceptably triangle-like. It's likely that the above is the type of triangle meant, since triangular numbers are well-studied. In any case, this assumption at least leads to a reasonable and interesting problem, although whether it has a unique solution remains to be seen. If it does, then I would consider that strong evidence that this is the formulation intended.

Comment: Well, as it's clear from mvw's answer that the solution *isn't* unique, maybe this isn't the correct formulation after all.

Comment: I also check the triangle disposition with 2 points added each rows and it give similar results. No idea how to find the correct question

Answer (score 2):

Note: I assumed the triangle split into two equal sized triangles, which is more specific than the question.

Here is a small Ruby program to check the first 10 million triangle numbers: 
[link](https://gist.github.com/1387d0446aae3d42ed3a)

It outputs the index $k$, the $k$-th triangle number, its half, and its index:

```
0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0
3 -> 6 -> 3 -> 2
20 -> 210 -> 105 -> 14
119 -> 7140 -> 3570 -> 84
696 -> 242556 -> 121278 -> 492
4059 -> 8239770 -> 4119885 -> 2870
23660 -> 279909630 -> 139954815 -> 16730
137903 -> 9508687656 -> 4754343828 -> 97512
803760 -> 323015470680 -> 161507735340 -> 568344
4684659 -> 10973017315470 -> 5486508657735 -> 3312554
```

Modulo bugs, it seems there are many solutions, like $(6,3)$, $(210,105)$, $(7140, 3570)$ ..

Most likely for a real world situation is the split 6 into 3 and 3 planes.

Note: I OEISed the first few numbers and got [A029549](https://oeis.org/A029549)

Comment: Once again showcasing the power of the OEIS.